# why i am getting an error in my SQL syntax as undefined index

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a problem with my php file. When submitting the form there is an error called "undefined index in my PHP file" and also

> Error: INSERT into `payment`
> (PID,PInvoice_no,p_description,unit_price,quantity,total)VALUES('','','',','','')
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '','','')' at line 1

I couldn't find the error though I tried several times. I tried to solve this but I couldn't solve it, so please help me with this.

**this is my html form**

```
<body>
        <div class-"logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" width="150" height="130" align="left" alt="logo"/>
        
        <a href="admin.php">
        <img src="images/homebutton.png" width="130" height="130" align="right" alt="Home"/></a>
        </div>
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        
        <div class="form2">
        <pre>   <b><font size="+5">Payment</font></b></pre>
    
        
        <table>
        <form name="payment" align="center" action="payment_file.php" method="GET">
        
<tr><td>Invoice_no  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td> <input type="text" name="PInvoice_no" size="11" id="PInvoice_no" required/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Payment description </td><td><input type="text" name="pay_description" size="50" id="p_description" required/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Unit price  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td><input type="text" name="UP" size="5" id="unit_price"/> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Quantity  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td><input type="number" name="quantity" size="20" id="quantity"/> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Total </td><td><input type="text" name="total" size="10" id="total" required/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><br /></td><td> </td><td> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   </td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Add" size="100" value="Add"/></td>
        </form>
        </table>
        
        </div>
</body>
```

**This is my php file**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('dbconnection.php');

        $PID = $_POST['PID'];
        $PInvoice_no = $_POST['PInvoice_no'];
        $p_description = $_POST['p_description'];
        $unit_price = $_POST['unit_price'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $total = $_POST['total'];
         
          
        $sql="INSERT into `payment` (PID,PInvoice_no,p_description,unit_price,quantity,total)VALUES('$PID','$PInvoice_no','$p_description',$unit_price','$quantity','$total')";
        
        
        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
        }
        
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: In the supplied variables in the SQL statement you are missing a single quote from before `$unit_price'` - that said your code is vulnerable to SQL injection ~ use `prepared statements` instead

Comment: And `method="GET"` needs to be `method="POST"`. That's why your values aren't populated. Notice how the PHP code is trying to read them from $_POST?

Comment: @ADyson - tbh I never even looked at the form

Comment: The HTML however is invalid - you cannot insert a FORM into a table element as you do here. The form must either wholly contain the table or itself be wholly contained within a single table cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify your HTML so that it is firstly valid markup and secondly sets the form's method to POST - like so:

```
<div class-'logo'>
    <img src='images/logo.png' width='150' height='130' align='left' alt='logo'/>
    <a href='admin.php'>
        <img src='images/homebutton.png' width='130' height='130' align='right' alt='Home'/>
    </a>
</div>

<div class='form2'>

    <pre>
        <b><font size='+5'>Payment</font></b>
    </pre>

    <form name='payment' align='center' method='POST'><!-- action='payment_file.php'  -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>PID</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='PID' size='11' value=23 required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice_no</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='PInvoice_no' size='11' value=123456789 required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Payment description</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pay_description' size='50' value='suspicious payment from a shady, underworld goblin' required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit price</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='unit_price' size='5' value=1000 /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td><input type='number' name='quantity' size='20' value=23 /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='total' size='10' required value=23000 /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input type='submit' name='Add' size='100' value='Add'/>
            </td>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

You should then change your PHP to use a `prepared statement` which solves the problem found with missing quotes and helps mitigate SQL injection attacks.

```
<?php

    #session_start();
    #include('dbconnection.php');

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['PID'],
        $_POST['PInvoice_no'],
        $_POST['pay_description'],
        $_POST['unit_price'],
        $_POST['quantity'],
        $_POST['total']
    ) ){
        
        $sql='INSERT into `payment` ( `PID`, `PInvoice_no`, `p_description`, `unit_price`, `quantity`, `total` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )';
        $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );
        
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $_POST['PID'], $_POST['PInvoice_no'], $_POST['pay_description'], $_POST['unit_price'], $_POST['quantity'], $_POST['total'] );
        $res=$stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        
        exit( $res ? 'New record created successfully' : 'bogus' );
    }
?>
```

Rather than using multiple `&nbsp;` &/or `<br />` tags you might find css options a better method ~ certainly leaves cleaner HTML code.

---

***UPDATE***

Following your comment about testing the above I realise I missed several inconsistencies in your form and php.

- You do not have a field `PID` in your form at all.
- You refer to elements in PHP by the HTML ID rather than the name

As, more often than not, ID attributes are not required I removed them from the HTML here and modified the names of the form input elements whilst also adding a new one for the `PID`. This has now been tested with a very basic table schema and the duffault data above.

```
mysql> describe payment;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| PID           | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| PInvoice_no   | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| p_description | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| unit_price    | decimal(10,0)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| quantity      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| total         | decimal(10,0)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from payment;
+----+-----+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+-------+
| id | PID | PInvoice_no | p_description                                      | unit_price | quantity | total |
+----+-----+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+-------+
|  1 |  23 | 123456789   | suspicious payment from a shady, underworld goblin |      1000  |       23 | 23000 |
+----+-----+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

[image: form]

Comment: I copied this code and tried it. It shows a blank page after submitting not showing any errors even. and also form data is not saved to the database.

Comment: The `isset()` portion I added was based upon the variables you were assigning in your code. Looking at the form, some of these names do NOT appear in the form - it is the `NAME` attribute, not the `ID` attribute that appears in the POST array

Comment: There is also no Form element even nearly called `PID`

Comment: It worked. I corrected the NAME attribute.and added PID to the form and there was an error in the sql syntax also, missing a comma, then it works.